# Unique values of a parent in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `projectuser` which `has_many` `activities`, and `activities` `belongs_to` `projectuser`. Now I have a collection of activities as `@activities` in a controller and I want to get the unique projectusers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@activities` is a simple ruby collection (e.g. Array), then use this:

```
Projectuser.where(id: @activities.map(&:projectuser_id).uniq)
```

However, if your `@activities` object is an ActiveRelation (the result of an association call or query api call), you can do a more efficient lookup like this:

```
Projectuser.joins(:activities).merge(@activities)
```

The reason it is more efficient is because it avoids building a literal list of ids, which can get significantly harder on a db engine at it gets larger.

Comment: Thanks, it is an ActiveRelation, so I used ``Projectuser.joins(:activities).merge(@activities).uniq`` with the added ``uniq`` to get only the unique values.